# titanium - converting a new project to a mobile project

Tags: titanium

I'm working with several fellow classmates on a simple mobile app in Titanium. I'm running into a problem though, as when I pull the files from github as a new project it isn't classified as a mobile project, just as a blank project. Basically, this keeps me from being able to run the project for any reason, the option to do so is just grayed out. The code works in a new project I create as a mobile app, but for some reason Titanium doesn't recognize the pulled project as something that can be run. I've confirmed that the deployment targets in the pulled project are checked for Android and Mobile Web, is there something else I should be looking for, or a command I need to enter?

Answer (score 2):

Okay, figured it out. I had to go into properties and under project natures I had to put a check next to 'Mobile'. Kind of painful how simple that was, but maybe my question/answer will help anyone else caught by this